# Liferay Dynamic Subquery on two tables

Tags: java, sql, subquery, liferay, dynamicquery

I need to access two attributes from two different tables via dynamic subquery.

```
create table DLFileVersion (
    uuid_ VARCHAR(75) null,
    fileVersionId LONG not null primary key,
    groupId LONG,
    companyId LONG,
    userId LONG,
    userName VARCHAR(75) null,
    createDate DATE null,
    etc... etc... etc...
    status INTEGER,
    statusByUserId LONG,
    statusByUserName VARCHAR(75) null,
    statusDate DATE null
);
```

and other table

```
create table DLFileEntry (
    uuid_ VARCHAR(75) null,
    fileEntryId LONG not null primary key,
    groupId LONG,
    companyId LONG,
    userId LONG,
    userName VARCHAR(75) null,
    version VARCHAR(75) null,
    size_ LONG,
);
```

I have to find a file by attributes from these two tables, the problem is, that I don't know how to make dynamic subquery with two attributes from DLFileVersion table which are status and userName ... I need to combinate these two attributes with whole DLFileEntry table, to perform a dynamic query using criterions obtained by user from a jsp page. 
Example:

```
SELECT DLFileVersion.userName, DLFileEntry.userName, status, version
FROM DLFileVersion, DLFileEntry
WHERE ....
```

Comment: Can you show an example with actual data and expected results?

Comment: User wants to find a document with this attributes:

lastUpdated = Joe Bloggs
uploadedBy = Joe Bloggs
status = Approved
version = 2.0 
the problem is that DLFileEntry table doesn't contain attribute status, and attribute username represents the autor of document (uploadedBy) while userName in DLFileVersion represents lastUpdater...
What I need is to check this two tables with Criterion RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("userName", "JoeBloggs") /from first table/ AND RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("userName", "JoeBloggs") /from second table/ AND RestrictionsFactoryUtil.eq("status", "approved") AND...

Comment: ...and get the document from DLFileEntry. 
But I'm not sure yet, if subquery is the right way to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you considered using a join instead of a subquery?

Comment: I have considered it, but found out, that dynamicQuery does not support joins, only subqueries, so I am a bit confused.

Comment: If you can produce a query with multiple FROM items, the result will be joined.

Comment: why not go for custom sql?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Custom SQL for joins:

https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.2/development/-/ai/develop-custom-sql-queries-liferay-portal-6-2-dev-guide-04-en

http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/02/getting-data-from-multiple-tables-in.html